# Drawing a Cube in WebGL

Tags: webgl

I am not sure what is the problem in this code, but when I try to draw lines of a cube which are far side (last 4 lines) from the camera view than the object disappear. However, I do able to draw 8 edge lines of the cube.

Lines (points) for the Cubes are as follows. Only first 8 lines (16 points) showed, but rest 4 lines (8 points) I couldn't add to the cube.

```
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//1
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//2

        vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//1
        vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//4

        vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//1
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//5

        vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//2
        vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//3

        vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//2
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//6

        vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//3
        vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//4

        vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//3
        vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//7

        vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//4
        vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0) //8
        /*
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//5
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//6
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//5
        vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0) //8
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//6
        vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//7
        vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//7
        vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0) //8
        */
```

Much appreciate any help.

Here is the Code:

```
    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    attribute  vec4 vPosition;
    attribute  vec4 vColor;
    varying vec4 fColor;

    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

    void main() 
    {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vPosition;
        fColor = vColor;
    } 
    </script>

    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    precision mediump float;

    varying vec4 fColor;

    void
    main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = fColor;
    }
    </script>

    var canvas;
    var gl;

    var NumVertices  = 24;

    var vertices = [
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//1
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//2
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//1
        vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//4
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//1
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//5
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//2
        vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//3
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//2
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//6
        vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//3
        vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//4
        vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//3
        vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//7
        vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//4
        vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0) //8
        /*
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//5
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//6
        vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//5
        vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0) //8
        vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//6
        vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//7
        vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//7
        vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0) //8
        */
    ];

    var vertexColors = [
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red

        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        /*
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        */
    ];

    var near = 0.3;
    var far = 10.0;
    var radius = 4.0;
    var theta  = 0.0;
    var phi    = 0.0;
    var dr = 5.0 * Math.PI/180.0;

    var  fovy = 90.0;  // Field-of-view in Y direction angle (in degrees)
    var  aspect;       // Viewport aspect ratio

    var modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
    var modelViewMatrixLoc, projectionMatrixLoc;
    var eye;
    const at = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    const up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);


    var program;
    var program_originline;

    var cBuffer;
    var vColor;
    var vBuffer;
    var vPosition;

    var l_vBuffer;
    var l_vPosition;
    var l_cBuffer;
    var l_vColor;

    window.onload = function init() {

        canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

        gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
        if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

        gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

        aspect =  canvas.width/canvas.height;

        gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
        program_originline = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
        program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );

        //CUBE Buffers
        cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
        //gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
        gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertexColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );    

        vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
        //gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
        //gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor);

        vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
        //gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
        gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

        vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );


        //Static Line
        var l_vertices = [
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(5.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0,  5.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0,  0.0,  5.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(-5.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0,  -5.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0,  0.0,  -5.0, 1.0),
            ];
        // Load the data into the GPU
        l_vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, l_vBuffer );
        gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(l_vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
        // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
        l_vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program_originline, "vPosition" );


        var l_colors = [
            vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
            vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),

            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
            vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
            ];
        l_cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, l_cBuffer );
        gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(l_colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

        l_vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program_originline, "vColor" );


        // buttons for viewing parameters
        document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function(){near  *= 1.1; far *= 1.1;};
        document.getElementById("Button2").onclick = function(){near *= 0.9; far *= 0.9;};
        document.getElementById("Button3").onclick = function(){radius *= 2.0;};
        document.getElementById("Button4").onclick = function(){radius *= 0.5;};
        document.getElementById("Button5").onclick = function(){theta += dr;};
        document.getElementById("Button6").onclick = function(){theta -= dr;};
        document.getElementById("Button7").onclick = function(){phi += dr;};
        document.getElementById("Button8").onclick = function(){phi -= dr;};

        render(); 
    }


    var render = function(){
        gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        //LINE PROGRAM
        gl.useProgram( program_originline );
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( l_vPosition );
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, l_vBuffer );
        gl.vertexAttribPointer( l_vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( l_vColor );
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, l_cBuffer );
        gl.vertexAttribPointer( l_vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );   

        gl.drawArrays( gl.LINES, 0, 12);

        modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program_originline, "modelViewMatrix" );
        projectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program_originline, "projectionMatrix" );

        eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.cos(phi), 
            radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.cos(theta));
        modelViewMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);
        projectionMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);

        gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix) );
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projectionMatrixLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix) );


        //CUBE PROGRAM
        gl.useProgram( program );
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
        gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor);
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
        gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
        gl.drawArrays( gl.LINES, 0, 18 );

        modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "modelViewMatrix" );
        projectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "projectionMatrix" );

        eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.cos(phi),radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.cos(theta));
        modelViewMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);
        projectionMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);

        gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix) );
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projectionMatrixLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix) );

        requestAnimFrame(render);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update the `drawArrays`'s last parameter from 18 to 24 (since there are 12 lines per cube and 2 vertices per line).

```
gl.drawArrays( gl.LINES, 0, 24 );
```

And of course remember to uncomment the lines in the `vertices` and `vertexColors` arrays (and make sure the arrays don't have any missing or extra commas in them).

Here is your code after I made all the necessary fixes:

```js
var canvas;
var gl;

var NumVertices  = 24;

var vertices = [
    vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//1
    vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//2
    vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//1
    vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//4
    vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//1
    vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//5
    vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//2
    vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//3
    vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//2
    vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//6
    vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//3
    vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//4
    vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//3
    vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//7
    vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),//4
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0), //8
    vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//5
    vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//6
    vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//5
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0), //8
    vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//6
    vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//7
    vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),//7
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0) //8
];

var vertexColors = [
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red

    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
];

var near = 0.3;
var far = 10.0;
var radius = 4.0;
var theta  = 0.0;
var phi    = 0.0;
var dr = 5.0 * Math.PI/180.0;

var  fovy = 90.0;  // Field-of-view in Y direction angle (in degrees)
var  aspect;       // Viewport aspect ratio

var modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
var modelViewMatrixLoc, projectionMatrixLoc;
var eye;
const at = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);


var program;
var program_originline;

var cBuffer;
var vColor;
var vBuffer;
var vPosition;

var l_vBuffer;
var l_vPosition;
var l_cBuffer;
var l_vColor;

window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

    aspect =  canvas.width/canvas.height;

    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    program_originline = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );

    //CUBE Buffers
    cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    //gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertexColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );    

    vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    //gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    //gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor);

    vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    //gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );


    //Static Line
    var l_vertices = [
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(5.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0,  5.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0,  0.0,  5.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(-5.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0,  -5.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0,  0.0,  -5.0, 1.0),
        ];
    // Load the data into the GPU
    l_vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, l_vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(l_vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
    l_vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program_originline, "vPosition" );


    var l_colors = [
        vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0),

        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
        ];
    l_cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, l_cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(l_colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    l_vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program_originline, "vColor" );


    // buttons for viewing parameters
    document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function(){near  *= 1.1; far *= 1.1;};
    document.getElementById("Button2").onclick = function(){near *= 0.9; far *= 0.9;};
    document.getElementById("Button3").onclick = function(){radius *= 2.0;};
    document.getElementById("Button4").onclick = function(){radius *= 0.5;};
    document.getElementById("Button5").onclick = function(){theta += dr;};
    document.getElementById("Button6").onclick = function(){theta -= dr;};
    document.getElementById("Button7").onclick = function(){phi += dr;};
    document.getElementById("Button8").onclick = function(){phi -= dr;};

    render(); 
}


var render = function(){
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    //LINE PROGRAM
    gl.useProgram( program_originline );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( l_vPosition );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, l_vBuffer );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( l_vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( l_vColor );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, l_cBuffer );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( l_vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );   

    gl.drawArrays( gl.LINES, 0, 12);

    modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program_originline, "modelViewMatrix" );
    projectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program_originline, "projectionMatrix" );

    eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.cos(phi), 
        radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.cos(theta));
    modelViewMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);
    projectionMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix) );
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projectionMatrixLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix) );


    //CUBE PROGRAM
    gl.useProgram( program );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor);
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.LINES, 0, 24 );

    modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "modelViewMatrix" );
    projectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "projectionMatrix" );

    eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.cos(phi),radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.cos(theta));
    modelViewMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);
    projectionMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix) );
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projectionMatrixLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix) );

    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/MV.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/initShaders.js"></script>

    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

        attribute  vec4 vPosition;
        attribute  vec4 vColor;
        varying vec4 fColor;

        uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
        uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

        void main() 
        {
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vPosition;
            fColor = vColor;
        } 
    </script>

    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

        precision mediump float;

        varying vec4 fColor;

        void
        main()
        {
            gl_FragColor = fColor;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="Button1" type="button">1</button>
      <button id="Button2" type="button">2</button>
      <button id="Button3" type="button">3</button>
      <button id="Button4" type="button">4</button>
      <button id="Button5" type="button">5</button>
      <button id="Button6" type="button">6</button>
      <button id="Button7" type="button">7</button>
      <button id="Button8" type="button">8</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Anton, Thank you very much for the solution. Just now I found where the problem is. While declaring the vertices for cube, I forget to put comma in line no 16th and 20th. You also have mentioned in ur solution "(and make sure the arrays don't have any missing or extra commas in them)". Thank you very much again, it saves me a lot of time.